# HeidiSQL color editor: change the green color of the 'string type' output in result set box?

Tags: color-scheme, heidisql

I went to: Tools → Preferences → SQL → String Literal → black

This change only took effect when I'm typing a string in the query box. This change doesn't take place in the output box.

May someone please tell me how to change the green color in the output box please? I find it uncomfortable to read.

I registered on the heidisql forum and have yet to get a confirmation email. Their forum also won't let me login.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered it:  Tools → Preferences → Text Formatting tab → Grid text colors → Select 'Text' from drop down menu → Then select color from the next drop down menu.

Comment: And just to clarify, it's Tools → Preferences → Grid Formatting tab → Grid text colors → Select 'Text' from drop down menu in HeidiSQL 9.5.0.